# Fusuma Album View video thumbs swaping

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, phasset

I am using Fusuma for my image and video gallery.
I have an issue with scrolling gallery View (FSAlbumView.swift) . while I scroll it swaps thumbs of video , or in place of a video thumb an image thumb come, It do not have any issues with thumbs of images, the problem is only with video thumbs.

Here is my code.

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("FSAlbumViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FSAlbumViewCell

    let currentTag = cell.tag + 1
    cell.tag = currentTag

    let asset = self.images[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    if(asset.mediaType == .Image){
        self.imageManager?.requestImageForAsset(asset,
                                                targetSize: cellSize,
                                                contentMode: .AspectFill,
                                                options: nil) {
                                                    result, info in

                                                    if cell.tag == currentTag {
                                                        cell.image = result
                                                    }

        }
    }else if(asset.mediaType == .Video){
        self.imageManager?.requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in
                //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                    let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset
            if asset?.URL.absoluteString != nil{
            self.videoURLArray.append([indexPath.row:(asset?.URL.absoluteString)!])
            }
                    if cell.tag == currentTag {
                        cell.video = asset?.URL
                       // self.videoURLArray[indexPath.row] = (asset?.URL.absoluteString)!
                        print(asset?.URL)

                    }
                    //..var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: asset!.URL)

                //})
            })
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We also had the same issue. What we did is giving below. Don't know whether its the right way.

Comment the below statements.

```
let currentTag = cell.tag + 1  
cell.tag = currentTag
```

add replace the if-else  block with the following code snippet

```
self.imageManager?.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: cellSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil){
                                                    result, info in


                                                    if(asset.mediaType == .Video){
                                                        self.imageManager?.requestAVAssetForVideo(asset, options: nil, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) in

                                                            let asset = asset as? AVURLAsset
                                                            if asset?.URL.absoluteString != nil{
                                                                self.videoURLArray.append([indexPath.row:(asset?.URL.absoluteString)!])
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                                    }
                                                    cell.image = result
 }
```